# Nested for-loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I've gotten my code to behave as expected except for one last bit.

I'm having problems with my last for-loop. I just need it to start on the right side (or right- justified) instead of how it is now - it's starting on the left side (it's left-justified).

Here's the output on my terminal (it's the last set (the 4th set) of asterisks I'm having an issue with).

[image]

Here's my code.

```
public class Triangles
{
  // draw four triangles
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int row;               // the row position
    int column;            // the column position
    int space;             // number of spaces to print
    int numLines = 10;     // the number of lines per triangle

    
    for (row = 1; row <= numLines; row++)
    {
       for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
         System.out.print("*");
       System.out.println();
    } // end first for-loop
    System.out.println();

   

    for (row = 1; row <= numLines; row++)
    {
        for (column = 10; column >= row; column--)
          System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    } // end second for-loop
    System.out.println();

    
      for (row = numLines; row >= 1; row--)
      {
         for (space = numLines; space > row; space--)
           System.out.print(" ");
         for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
           System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
       } // end third for loop
       System.out.println();
      
       // !! This is the for-loop I'm having an issue with!!
       for (row = numLines; row >=1; row--) {
         for (space = numLines; space < numLines; space--)
           System.out.print(" ");
         for (column = numLines; column >= row; column--) 
           System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
       } // end fourth for loop
   } // end main
} // end class Triangle
```

Thanks in advance for all your help : )

Comment: 3rd shape and 4th shape are same. Just start the 3rd loop from opposite direction in 4th loop and leave the other thing as it is. I  have answered below. Let me know, if it is your desired output.

Comment: In the past, I always give this kind of question to my students. To make it easy for you, you can try to change the output into the count of * and <space>. for example if n=3 then the output will be line 1: 2<space> 1*, line 2: 1<space> 2*, line 3: 0<space> 3*. Then adjust the number and using basic for(i=0;i<n;i++) it will repeat n times. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

*3rd shape and 4th shape are almost same. Just start the 1st loop in 3rd shape from opposite direction in 4th shape and leave the other thing as it is.*

```
    int row;               // the row position
    int column;            // the column position
    int space;             // number of spaces to print
    int numLines = 10;     // the number of lines per triangle

      
      // !! This is the for-loop I'm having an issue with!!
      for (row = 1; row <=numLines ; row++) {
         for (space = numLines; space > row; space--)
           System.out.print(" ");
         for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
           System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
       } // end third for loop
       System.out.println(); // end fourth for loop
```